# Undefined symbols compiling against AWS SDK for CPP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-cpp

I'm trying to use the AWS C++ SDK from an Unreal Engine plugin, but I'm getting errors for various symbols that the code seems to expect to be externally defined; here are some of the ones it's complaining about:

- `_MSC_VER`
- `__clang_analyzer__`
- `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`
- `AWS_DEEP_CHECKS`
- `AWS_USE_IO_COMPLETION_PORTS`

I'm compiling with `clang` on Mac. Searching the SDK source for any of these, the only places I can find any of them defined are in make files. Shouldn't building the SDK have generated a .h or something with the correctly defined values for all these? I can't find any SDK documentation that mentions any requirement to define these or other symbols before consuming the SDK APIs.

I should probably note that `make` ended with 2 test failing, and I didn't run `make install` (I want the SDK to live in the Unreal plugin, not be installed system wide) so it's possible there's something missing due to that?

[Edit: after disabling the tests (two of which are failing) I was able to `make install` but am still getting undefined symbol errors from the installed header files :-/]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

I found the following document.

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/gametech/how-to-integrate-the-aws-c-sdk-with-unreal-engine/

The following additions were needed to [MODULE_NAME].Build.cs
`bEnableUndefinedIdentifierWarnings = false;`